# Include Graphs in github via RMarkdown html output

Tags: html, github, r-markdown

Can I have a github project present my code, graphs and tables in a single document like an RMarkdown file does? When I upload my html RMarkdown file, github changes the presentation to something less presentable. The best I've been able to do is just push my code from R, which handles all the code but no graphs.

This is the more complete file I pushed right from R, however the html file in this repository is the RMarkdown file I uploaded which didn't come over as I'd hoped.
https://github.com/jconns/Driven-Data/blob/main/restaurant_visitors.R

If anyone has best practices to have an all inclusive github file, similar to an RMarkdown output, I would very much appreciate it!